# Creating a boxplot using bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, data-analysis, boxplot

How to create a boxplot like this one using **the bokeh library in python**?

```
df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.boxplot(x=df["age"])
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I create a single box plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72059571/how-can-i-create-a-single-box-plot)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using some random data as input:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
output_notebook()

series = pd.Series(list(np.random.randint(0,60,100))+[101]) # one outlier added by hand
```

Here is the math the boxplot is based on, some quantiles are calculated and the inter quantile range as well as the mean.

```
qmin, q1, q2, q3, qmax = series.quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
iqr = q3 - q1
upper = q3 + 1.5 * iqr
lower = q1 - 1.5 * iqr
mean = series.mean()

out = series[(series > upper) | (series < lower)]

if not out.empty:
    outlier = list(out.values)
```

This stays the same for both solutions.

#### vertical boxplot

```
k = 'age'
p = figure(
    tools="save",
    x_range= [k], # enable categorical axes
    title="Boxplot",
    plot_width=400,
    plot_height=500,
)

upper = min(qmax, upper)
lower = max(qmin, lower)

hbar_height = (qmax - qmin) / 500

# stems
p.segment([k], upper, [k], q3, line_color="black")
p.segment([k], lower, [k], q1, line_color="black")

# boxes
p.vbar([k], 0.7, q2, q3, line_color="black")
p.vbar([k], 0.7, q1, q2, line_color="black")

# whiskers (almost-0 height rects simpler than segments)
p.rect([k], lower, 0.2, hbar_height, line_color="black")
p.rect([k], upper, 0.2, hbar_height, line_color="black")

if not out.empty:
    p.circle([k] * len(outlier), outlier, size=6, fill_alpha=0.6)

show(p)
```

[image: vertical boxplot]

#### horizontal boxplot

To create a horizontal boxplot `hbar` is used instead of `vbar` and the order is changes in the `segement`s and in the `rect`s.

```
k = 'age'
p = figure(
    tools="save",
    y_range= [k],
    title="Boxplot",
    plot_width=400,
    plot_height=500,
)

upper = min(qmax, upper)
lower = max(qmin, lower)

hbar_height = (qmax - qmin) / 500

# stems
p.segment(upper, [k], q3, [k], line_color="black")
p.segment(lower, [k], q1, [k], line_color="black")

# boxes
p.hbar([k], 0.7, q2, q3, line_color="black")
p.hbar([k], 0.7, q1, q2, line_color="black")

# whiskers (almost-0 height rects simpler than segments)
p.rect(lower, [k], 0.2, hbar_height, line_color="black")
p.rect(upper, [k], 0.2, hbar_height, line_color="black")

if not out.empty:
    p.circle(outlier, [k] * len(outlier),  size=6, fill_alpha=0.6)

show(p)
```

[image: horizontal boxplot]